# How to reference a file in another repo from pipeline yaml file applying Terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I'm certain I'm just looking for the right syntax here and need help finding it.  I'm trying to create a configuration where the Terraform code is all in one repo (CodeRepo) but the .tfvars files are in another repo (ConfigRepo).  The pipeline is run from CodeRepo.  In the Yaml, the relevant parts are:

```
parameters:
  - name: Environment
    type: string
    values:
      - dev
      - qa
      - prod

  - name: applyOrDestroy
    type: string
    values:
      - apply
      - destroy

  - name: Role
    type: string
    values:
      - iam-role-automation
      - iam-role-testing
      - iam-role-debug

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: ConfigRepository
      type: git
      name: TechOps/ConfigRepo
```

terraform -chdir="modules/${{parameters.Role}}" ${{parameters.applyOrDestroy}} -auto-approve -input=false -var-file **ConfigRepository/vars/${{parameters.Environment}}/terraform.tfvars**

The contents of the ConfigRepo are a directory named "vars", which has a subdirectory named "dev", which contains the terraform.tfvars file.

What is the syntax to use in the Terraform command after -var-file in bold above to get it to read the terraform.tfvars file from the ConfigRepo?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what build tool this YAML is being used to support.

Comment: It's for a Terraform module to create IAM roles in AWS.

Comment: What tool runs the pipeline? Codebuild? travisCI?